# kernel configuration related to interrupt smp_affinity

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel, kvm

For a Fedora Core VM, running kernel-4.8, what kernel configuration(s) relates to the value of smp_affinity for interrupts, see below e.g.,

```
~]# cat /proc/irq/33/smp_affinity
2
```

Answer (score 2):

IRQs have an associated **"affinity"** property, *smp_affinity*, which defines the **CPU cores** that are allowed to execute the *ISR* for that *IRQ*.

The interrupt affinity value for a particular IRQ number is stored in the associated `/proc/irq/IRQ_NUMBER/smp_affinity` file, which can be viewed and modified by the root user. The value stored in this file is a **hexadecimal bit-mask** representing all CPU cores in the system.

In your case the value for smp_affinity is **2**, means that the IRQ can be serviced on the `CPU 1` (2nd core).

You can set the smp_affinity as well:

```
echo "1" > /proc/irq/67/smp_affinity for 1st core
echo "3" > /proc/irq/67/smp_affinity for assign on 1st and 2nd core
echo "5" > /proc/irq/67/smp_affinity for assigning 1st and 3rd core
echo "f" > /proc/irq/67/smp_affinity for assigning all the core
```